# parseExpression in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am integrating [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) in an existing project.

I am writing a token parser to parse a custom tag that is similiar to the `{% render %}` tag.

My tag looks like:

```
{% mytag 'somestring' with { 'name': name, 'color': 'green' } %}
```

where name is defined by `{% set name = 'foo' %}`

I am able to parse `somestring` without any issues.

This is the code used to parse the stuff in the `with{ }`:

```
$Stream = $this->parser->getStream();

if ( $Stream->test( \Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'with' ) )
{
    $Stream->next();

    $parsedParameters = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
    $parameters       = $this->parser->getEnvironment()->compile( $parsedParameters );

    var_dump( $parameters ); //string 'array( "name" => $this->getContext( $context, "name" ), "color" => "green" )' (length=72)

    foreach ( $parsedParameters->getIterator() as $parameter )
    {
        //var_dump($ parameter->getAttribute('value') );
    }
}
```

My goal is to turn `'name': name, 'color': 'green'` into an associative array within the token parser:

```
array(
   'name' => 'foo',
   'color': 'green',
)
```

As the documentation is quite sparse and the code in the library is uncommented, I am not sure how to do this. If I loop through `$parsedParameters`, I get 4 elements consisting of the array key and an array value. However, as `name` is a variable with a type `Twig_Node_Expression_Name`, I am unsure as to how I can compile it to get the compiled value. Currently, I have found a way to compile that node, but all it gives me is a string containing a PHP expression which I can't use.

How can I turn the parsed expression into an associative array?

Answer (score 0):

Okey. I guess I was able to solve that. Not to pretty, but should work.

```
$Stream = $this->parser->getStream();

if ( $Stream->test( \Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'with' ) )
{
    $Stream->next();

    $parsedParameters = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
    $parameters       = $this->parser->getEnvironment()->compile( $parsedParameters );

    var_dump( $parameters ); //string 'array( "name" => $this->getContext( $context, "name" ), "color" => "green" )' (length=72)

    $index = null;
    $value = null;

    foreach ( $parsedParameters->getIterator() as $parameter )
    {
        if ( $parameter->hasAttribute( 'value' ) )
        {
            $index = $parameter->getAttribute( 'value' );
        }
        elseif ( $parameter->hasAttribute( 'name' ) )
        {
            $value = $parameter->getAttribute( 'name' );
        }

        if ( isset( $index, $value ) )
        {
            $params[ $index ] = $value;

            $index = null;
            $value = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So here I have array `params`, that I can pass to Custom node.

```
$params = var_export( $properties['params'], true );
unset( $fieldProperties['params'] );
```

Now I just did following:

```
$Compiler
    ->write( "\$params = array();\n" )

    ->write( "foreach ( {$params} as \$searchFor => \$replaceWith )\n" )
    ->write( "{\n" )
    ->write( "\t\$params[ \$searchFor ] = str_replace( \$replaceWith, \$context[\$replaceWith], \$replaceWith );\n" )
    ->write( "}\n" )

    ->write( "var_dump( \$params );\n" );
```

This should be it.

Also I see, that you where talking about TokenParser, but sadly I haven't found the solution to turn it over there.